# How to do multi-part upload with Python requests library AND unicode filename?

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, python-requests

I'm trying to upload a file to JIRA using its REST API. Uploads are done as multi-part POST. The code works fine so long as the filenames are ASCII. If they contain any non-ASCII characters, JIRA gives a 500 error.

I've tried to correct that by encoding the filename in the POST operation and the file upload succeeds but JIRA displays the ASCII version of the encoded filename, rather than decoding the filename into the original UTF-8.

Here is a snippet of the Python code:

```
files = {'file': (urllib2.quote(zd_attachment['file_name'].encode('utf8')), open('/tmp/%s' % zd_attachment['file_name'], 'rb'), zd_attachment['content_type'])}
mp_header = {'X-Atlassian-Token': 'nocheck'}
r = requests.post("%s/rest/api/2/issue/%s/attachments" % (jira_url, issue_id), headers=mp_header, files=files, auth=jira_auth)
```

Am I using the wrong method to encode the filename? Have I missed something else out in order to correctly handle the Unicode filename?

Comment: You don't need to use `urllib2.quote()` I *think*. Certainly `requests` will use any encoding required, and you don't need to use URL encoding in *multipart mime headers*. Did you try `(zd_attachment['file_name'].encode('utf8'), open('/tmp/%s' % zd_attachment['file_name'], 'rb'), zd_attachment['content_type'])`?

Comment: That said, I don't have all that much confidence in Jira handling the filenames correctly.

Answer (score 6):

Urllib3 uses the wrong method of encoding for non-ASCII filenames ([issue](https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/issues/303), [pull request](https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/pull/856)). A workaround is to create your own [PreparedRequest](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#prepared-requests) or implement an [auth handler](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/#new-forms-of-authentication) and change the body of the request just before sending it. I have some examples in my [blog post](http://linuxonly.nl/docs/68/167_Uploading_files_with_non_ASCII_filenames_using_Python_requests.html) about this.

Comment: Off topic: I have two quick questions about your blog. 1. Was the [“Block iframe loading” article](http://www.sjoerdlangkemper.nl/2016/07/15/block-iframe-loading/) deleted? 2. Do you plan to switch to HTTPS anytime soon? Your articles are great, btw 

Comment: Thanks! I updated the date of the [iframe article](http://www.sjoerdlangkemper.nl/2016/07/20/block-iframe-loading/). I didn't realize this broke any existing links. I do want to provide HTTPS, but I have to figure out which hosting/CDN solution to use.

Comment: I see. The URL change is unfortunate. I hope you find a solution that doesn’t result in 404 when articles are updated .

Answer (score 3):

> Am I using the wrong method to encode the filename?

The bad news is, there isn't really any widely-accepted method of encoding non-ASCII and other troublesome characters (like quotes) into filenames. The `Content-Disposition; filename` parameter is a thing of woeful unreliability on the web.

`requests`/`urllib3` tries so hard to be good. If a filename contains non-ASCII characters it tries to encode them using the crazy `filename*=` header parameter scheme put forward for MIME by RFC 2231 (source: `urllib3.fields.format_header_param`).

This is in fact the right thing to do for the `Content-Disposition` header in HTTP file download responses (per [RFC5987](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5987)), and some browsers even support that now, but form submissions aren't covered by this.

Nothing on the server side supports this form of encoding, so I suspect JIRA is probably seeing a file upload field without a `filename` (because it only has a `filename*`) and throwing its toys out of the pram.

HTML5, which has taken over definition of the `multiple/form-data` media type, now disowns this encoding scheme:

> User agents must not use the RFC 2231 encoding suggested by RFC 2388.

Instead:

> File names included in the generated multipart/form-data resource (as part of file fields) must use the character encoding selected above

So you should be passing in a Unicode string for the filename and `urllib3` should encode that to the same encoding used for the rest of the form (eg UTF-8). That you can't is IMO a bug that should be reported against `urllib3`. For the moment you may have to settle for ASCII-only filenames.

Aside: unfortunately we are still far from salvation here. As well as legacy browsers and their arbitrary encodings, HTML5 still keeps life nice and woolly by allowing browsers to apply additional arbitrary unrecoverable mangling:

> the precise name may be approximated if necessary (e.g. newlines could be removed from file names, quotes could be changed to "%22", and characters not expressible in the selected character encoding could be replaced by other characters).

Comment: JIRA does seem to be properly supporting the Content-Disposition header because if I change the files code to hard-wire the filename to "fred.png", that is the filename JIRA uses. I've compared the network traffic of the upload from my code vs the network traffic of an upload done in a browser. The encodings are slightly different (e.g. space is + instead of %20) but I'm now asking Atlassian if it is a JIRA issue.

Comment: Yes, it supports the `filename=` parameter. It (or whatever `multipart/form-data` parsing library it is using) does not support the `filename*=` parameter (asterisk because RFC 2231 parameter encoding). If you feed a non-ASCII filename into `requests` you get an RFC 2231-encoded parameter, and HTML5 sez that isn't supposed to happen. So this is the fault of `urllib3` and not JIRA. `+` and `%20` don't come into it, URL-encoding is not used for filename parameters.

Answer (score 0):

This issue should now be fixed. As of v1.25.3, urllib3 is using HTML5 encoding of non-ASCII filenames ([merged PR](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/pull/1492)).

I have recently tried uploading attachments to Jira via REST API using the requests library, and there was no problem with filenames anymore.

The `files` parameter to requests can be specified this way (make sure *not* to URL-encode the filename):

```
files = {'file': (zd_attachment['file_name'], open('/tmp/%s' % zd_attachment['file_name'], 'rb'), zd_attachment['content_type'])}
```